# Using abstract Hilbert spaces to solve differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

There are techniques for solving PDE's, such as Fock-Schwinger method in physics, which involve translating the problem from the language of distributions to the language of the abstract Hilbert spaces.

For example, the Green's function equation is:
$$L(i\partial_x,x)G(x,x')= \delta(x-x')$$

A typical approach to deal with such equations is to note that we can choose vectors in Hilbert space as:
$$\langle x|x'\rangle  = \delta(x-x')$$
and, having this in mind, move $x$ and $i\partial_x$ "into" Hilbert space according to the rule:
$$i\partial_x \langle x|x'\rangle  = \langle x|P|x'\rangle  [1]$$ 
$$x \langle x|x'\rangle  = \langle x|Q|x'\rangle  [2]$$
where $P$ is chosen to commute with $Q$ as $[P,Q]=i * I$.

Therefore, inside bra-ket a linear operator $L$ is represented as:
$$L(i\partial_x,x)\langle x|x'\rangle  = \langle x|L(P,Q)|x'\rangle $$
and analytic functions of $L$, such as $exp(itL)$, will move into bra-ket with some additional terms due to commutation.

My question is the following. **On what mathematical grounds can we use rules [1] and [2]?** I see that they are somehow related to the Stone - von Neumann theorem, but I don't see the exact justification. Moreover, $\langle x|x'\rangle $ is being normalized in terms of distributions, not scalars, that is kind of a generalization to the usual notion of vector spaces with dot product, **which also needs justification**.

**Any textbook on Hilbert spaces or Quantum Mechanics that clarifies these rules?** (I mean, in a more or less strict way, not "on the physical grounds")
Is there any other book which highly exploits this Hilbert space technique to solve different kind of problems?

I proved similar relations in terms of distributions:
$$\delta(x-x') = \int dX \space \delta(X-x) \space \delta(X-x')$$
$$x \space \delta(x-x') = \int dX \space \delta(X-x) \space x \space \delta(X-x')$$
and by definition of the derivative in the space of distributions
$$\partial_x  \delta(X-x) \to -\partial_X  \delta(X-x) \to  +\delta(X-x)\partial_X$$
I finally get:
$$i\partial_x \space \delta(x-x') = \int dX \space \delta(X-x) \space i\partial_X \space \delta(X-x')$$
which looks like a dot product in Hilbert space if with make a map:
$$\delta(X-x) \to |x\rangle $$
$$\int dX \space \delta(X-x) \space \delta(X-x') \space \to \space \langle x|x'\rangle $$

And also, I have another question. **Is there a proof that also justifies this kind of a map between distribution-like objects to Hilbert space vectors?**

Comment: [Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Volume 2, Reed and Simon](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics.html?id=14XvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) and other books in that series.

Comment: There is also "Rigged Hilbert Space" [which is an attempt to put the Quantum Mechanics Bra-Ket notation, of Dirac, on rigorous mathematical footing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304550/rigged-hilbert-space-in-quantum-mechanics-and-generalized-notion-of-sequence) but it does  not make calculations or proofs easy.